# How to fix "Undefined variable: collaborators"?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing collaborators adding methods to my project management application. this is my collaborators add form.
`colllaborators/form.blade.php`

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:15px;padding:10px;">
        <h4 class="page-header">
            Collaborators
        </h4>
        @if( $collaborators)
           @foreach( $collaborators as $collaborator)
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" style="margin-top:5px;padding:4px;width:35px;"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->collaborator_id }}"
```

routes

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/collaborators', [
    'uses' => 'Project\Collaborators\Controller@addCollaborator',
    'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.create',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but when I click to collaborators adding buttons following error messages displayed.

```
Undefined variable: collaborators (View: C:\Users\Flex\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)
```

how can I fix this problem
**edited**

```
class ProjectCollaboratorsController extends Controller
{

    public function addCollaborator(Request $request, $id, Collaboration $collaboration)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'collaborator'     => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

       $collaborator_username           = substr(trim($request->input('collaborator')),1);
       $collaboration->project_id       = $id;
       if( is_null($this->getId($collaborator_username)))
       {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user does not exist');
       }

       $collaborator = $this->isCollaborator($id, $this->getId($collaborator_username));
       if(! is_null($collaboration))
       {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user is already a collaborator on this project');
       }

       $collaboration->collaborator_id  = $this->getId($collaborator_username);
       $collaboration->save();

       return redirect()->back()->with('info', "{$collaborator_username} has been added to your project successfully");
    }

    private function getId($username)
    {
        $result = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        return (is_null($result)) ? null : $result->id;
    }


    private function isCollaborator($projectId, $collaboratorId)
    {
        return Collaboration::where('project_id', $projectId)
                            ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
                            ->first();
    }

}
```

**see My other part of the form**

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.create', $project->id) }}">
```

**collaborator form route**

```
Route::get('/collaborators', function(){ 
   return view('collaborators.form'); 
})->name('collaborators.form');
```

Comment: How about showing controller?

Comment: please see my edited question I am showing all my projectCollaborator controller

Comment: `addCollaborator` processes post-request. What controller processes GET-request which shows the form?

Comment: see My form post in the edited question

Comment: Where are you using the view in the controller? Also, use: `@if (isset($collaborators))`.

Comment: acually I do not use show method to the controller

Comment: What route shows the form?

Comment: please see my edited **collaborator form route**

Comment: no idea..........

Comment: Can you post the complete form too?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/dzswkhym/ for form.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form page, you are checking `@if( $collaborators)` which checks if the `$collaborators` variable is not empty and then runs the `foreach` below it.

After you submit your form, you add the collaborator and redirect back with no `collaborators`. The if condition then tries to check if the variable is empty. At this point the variable has not been defined and hence it throws that error. To fix this error, return redirect back with the `collaborators` like this:

```
 public function addCollaborator(Request $request, $id, Collaboration $collaboration)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'collaborator'     => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

       $collaborator_username           = substr(trim($request->input('collaborator')),1);
       $collaboration->project_id       = $id;
       if( is_null($this->getId($collaborator_username)))
       {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user does not exist');
       }

       $collaborator = $this->isCollaborator($id, $this->getId($collaborator_username));
       if(! is_null($collaboration))
       {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user is already a collaborator on this project');
       }

       $collaboration->collaborator_id  = $this->getId($collaborator_username);
       $collaboration->save();
//Get all collaborators 
  $collaborators = Collaboration::all(); //if this is how you get all collaborators
//Get the project too
 $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
       return redirect()->back()->with(['collaborators'=>$collaborators,'project'=>$project,'info'=> "{$collaborator_username} has been added to your project successfully"]);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Using the `with` method puts the data in the session, i would suggest that you manually redirect to the view and flash the `message` to that view.

```
public function addCollaborator(Request $request, $id, Collaboration $collaboration)
        {
           $this->validate($request, [
                'collaborator'     => 'required|min:5',
            ]);

           $collaborator_username           = substr(trim($request->input('collaborator')),1);
           $collaboration->project_id       = $id;
           if( is_null($this->getId($collaborator_username)))
           {
                return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user does not exist');
           }

           $collaborator = $this->isCollaborator($id, $this->getId($collaborator_username));
           if(! is_null($collaboration))
           {
                return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'This user is already a collaborator on this project');
           }

           $collaboration->collaborator_id  = $this->getId($collaborator_username);
           $collaboration->save();
    //Get all collaborators 
      $collaborators = Collaboration::all(); //if this is how you get all collaborators
     //Get the project too
       $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
           return redirect()->route('collaborators.form',['collaborators'=>$collaborators,'project'=>$project])->with('info',"{$collaborator_username} has been added to your project successfully");
        }
```

**Edit 2**

I have changed all the `return redirect()->back()`'s

```
public function addCollaborator(Request $request, $id, Collaboration $collaboration)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'collaborator'     => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

       $collaborator_username           = substr(trim($request->input('collaborator')),1);
       $collaboration->project_id       = $id;

       //Get the project too
       $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

       if( is_null($this->getId($collaborator_username)))
       {
            return redirect()->route('collaborators.form',['project'=>$project])->with('warning', 'This user does not exist');
       }

       $collaborator = $this->isCollaborator($id, $this->getId($collaborator_username));
       if(! is_null($collaboration))
       {
            return redirect()->route('collaborators.form',['project'=>$project])->with('warning', 'This user is already a collaborator on this project');
       }

       $collaboration->collaborator_id  = $this->getId($collaborator_username);
       $collaboration->save();

       return redirect()->route('collaborators.form',['project'=>$project])->with('info',"{$collaborator_username} has been added to your project successfully");
    }
```

And change your `routes` to

```
Route::get('/project/{project}/collaborators', function($id){ 
       $collaborators = Collaboration::all();
       $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
       return view('collaborators.form',compact('collaborators','project')); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

Comment: now got this error **Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)**

Comment: Do you have a `project` variable on the page too?

Comment: can you post the content of the whole page on jsfiddle?

Comment: above jsfeddle include my whole form.blade.php file, yes in my form action has **project** variable plase see it

Comment: Yes ..i have seen it

Comment: What is the name of your project model?

Comment: is it `Project`??

Comment: And dont forget to change all the `return redirect()->back()`'s

Comment: Which answer are you using, the first or second?

Comment: what did you mean by **And dont forget to change all the return redirect()->back()'s**

Comment: Use the Edit 2.

Comment: ok my form route is as this **{{ route('projects.collaborators.create', $project->id) }}** then how can I paste it in the controller here **return redirect()->route('name_of_the_form_route',['collaborators'=>$collaborators,'project'=>$project])->with('info',"{$collaborator_username} has been added to your project successfully");
    }**

Comment: add the contents of your `routes/web.php` to jsfiddle

Comment: I have edited the answer. And dont forget to use the `Edit 2` instead

Comment: occured this error **Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)** and form error code is **<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.create', $project->id) }}">**

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Just a minute.. Im trying it on my computer.. ill get back to you shortly

Comment: if you need I have updated my collaborators form buttons also https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/dzswkhym/3/

Comment: now got **FatalErrorException in routes.php line 138: Class 'Collaboration' not found**

Comment: do `\App\Collaboration::all()`

Comment: what is the namespace of your `Collaboration` model

Comment: You can paste the content of your `Collaboration` model in the jsfiddle

Comment: wait a minitu I miss add namespace

Comment: I fixed name space problem but now got new error as **SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ddd.project_collaborator' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `project_collaborator`)**

Comment: paste the content of your `Collaboration` and `Project` models in jsfiddle

Comment: see in javascript section for collaboration and project models https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/dzswkhym/5/

Comment: have you created the `project_collaborator` migration?

Comment: Have you run php artisan migrate??

Comment: ok I fixed my mistaken 'project_collaborators' to 'project_collaborator' but now again got this error **Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\collaborators\form.blade.php)**

Comment: Add the namesapce

Comment: yes now I can see My project collaboration form, but when I am going to add collaborators this got this error **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = Mickle Mark limit 1)**

Comment: That means you dont have a `username` column on your `users` table.. I think you should mark my answer now since the problem has been resolved

Comment: please see My project_collaborator migration file in javascript section https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/dzswkhym/6/

Comment: its a problem with your `users` migration not your `project_collaborator`

Comment: My users table have 'name' column name how can I change it? can you help to this new problem

Comment: in your `getId` change `$result = User::where('username', $username)->first();` to `$result = User::where('name', $username)->first();`

Comment: Thanks Norris for your Nice support it is great friend

Comment: like get your email for more tech discussions

Comment: actually not save project_collaboration table data but not occurred any errors

Comment: good can you gess why did not save project collaborator data on the tabele when I add collaborator name woth @ mark and click add user button only page refresh no any data saving here...

Comment: I don't get you